# Is there any way to proportionate the old and new document in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr8

I have solr integration for billions of records and search is working, but the need is to enhance the search result output..

We need to have proportion between popular + old and new data
And lower the ratio of data from same lot in the output result

For example-

1. Popularity - 20%
2. fresh data- taken in the last 6 months 30%)
3. old data- Older than 6 months 30%
4. same shoot (repeats) 10%

I have tried to integrate the "boost" but it only returns new data..

`product(recip(ms(NOW,active_date),6.33e-11,1,1),log(popularity_score),image_boost_score,collection_boost_score,clusterboost)`

Solarconfig.xml- Query handler

````
 <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <str name="wt">json</str>
     <str name="indent">true</str>
     
      <!-- Query settings -->
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
         title^50 title_no_stemmer^50 keywords^40 title_stemmer^30 title_porter_stemmer^25 photographer_name^20 photographer_name_no_stemmer keywords_stemmer^4 keywords_porter_stemmer^3 file_name_phrase file_name media_id
      </str>
      
      <str name="boost">
         product(recip(ms(NOW,active_date),6.33e-11,1,1),log(popularity_score),image_boost_score,collection_boost_score,clusterboost)
      </str>
      
      <str name="mm">100%</str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="rows">20</str>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
      
      <!-- Faceting defaults -->
      <str name="facet">on</str>
      <str name="facet.missing">false</str>
      <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
      <str name="facet.field">media_type</str>
      <str name="facet.field">orientation</str>
      <str name="facet.field">people</str>
      <str name="facet.field">style</str>
      <str name="facet.field">collection_id</str>
      <str name="facet.field">location</str>

   </lst>
   <arr name="last-components">
       <str>elevator</str>
   </arr>
 </requestHandler>```
````

Comment: are there any date fields for the documents like createdDate, updatedDate? if not it would be good to add them in order to identify the old ones and new ones

Comment: yes there is field 'active_date'

Comment: then you can use the active_date field to find the new/latest documents. either by sorting or creating a facet of the date range

Comment: Yes I have did that if you check "boost" code and it always showing new data in 1st page.. I need mixing of new and old data

Comment: There is no need to use `product` between each of the terms, this will lead to every term affecting the score dispropriately and is hard to tune. Instead use the `^<boost>` syntax for each one and look at the debug output to see how much each field / function affects the score, then start tuning the necessary values to get the priorities you like.

Comment: @MatsLindh can you share some code snippets or suggestion links

Comment: There are examples of applying multiple boosts in the edismax and dismax reference guide pages: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/the-dismax-query-parser.html#bf-boost-functions-parameter - append `&debug=all` to your URL to get debug output for each hit.

Comment: @MatsLindh I have tried the solution but, it is not showing mix results of old and new data. It is only showing new data of first page

Comment: @MatsLindh please help me

Comment: There really isn't much more to say; use the debug=all functionality to see how each document gets scored, then tweak your boosts to get the behavior you're looking for (i.e. how much oldness for a document counts, how much the other terms count, etc.)